# simple HTML/CSS buble chat

Tags: html, css

i want make simple buble chat using css. with basic css (not CSS3) because the chat run on IE and loaded by VB program.
i use float left and right, but i got issue like this pict
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

bubble left and right in a row. and what i want is like this pict[image]

this is my sample code

```html
<div style="width:600px;">
 <div style="width:100%;">
  <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius</span>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%;">
  <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%;">
  <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%;">
  <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%;">
  <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The </span>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%;">
  <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius elements.</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the css

```
div { clear:both;  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code with clearfix:

```html
<div style="width:600px;">
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius</span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The </span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;">
    <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius elements.</span>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to add extra div elements. Just put the `clear:both;` on the surrounding element (that one with `width:100%`)

Comment: right, it can be and like that and with less HTML, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work

```
div {clear: both;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="width:600px;">
 <div style="display: block; width: 100%; float: left;">
  <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius</span>
 </div>
 <div style="display: block; width: 100%; float: right;">
  <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
 </div>
 <div style="display: block; width: 100%; float: right;">
  <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
 </div>
 <div style="display: block; width: 100%; float: left;">
  <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</span>
 </div>
 <div style="display: block; width: 100%; float: right;">
  <span style="background:#ff4d4d;padding:10px;float:right;margin-top:5px;">The </span>
 </div>
 <div style="display: block; width: 100%; float: left;">
  <span style="background:#e5e5e5;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:5px;">The border-radius elements.</span>
 </div>
```