# CSS Chat Bubbles with float

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a chat window with messages from the user on the right and messages from the other person on the  left. At first, I tried doing this without `floats` and failed. Doing some research I found that this was usually done using [floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915094/simple-html-css-buble-chat). I rewrote it using `floats` but it still isn't working.

Update: Are **floats** the best solution for this type of design?

```css
.user {
  float: right;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.friend {
  float: left;
  background-color: orchid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="user clearfix">
    Have you completed the css chat tutorial
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="friend clearfix">
    No I did not.
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="user clearfix">
    Is it working?
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="friend clearfix">
    NO :(
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are floats best solution?

I think that's relative to the developer and situation. There is no 'wrong' way, if that's what you are asking. But there are ways that help you in the long run if you want to be flexible and add more features. Here is an example using flex properties:

```css
body { 
  background-color: snow; 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
body div {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.user {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.friend {
  background-color: orchid;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="user">
    Have you completed the css chat tutorial
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="friend">
    No I did not.
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="user">
    Is it working?
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="friend">
    NO :(
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` not useful for chats. Because one person can send two consecutive messages.

Comment: very good point @DogukanCavus i'll update to just `.friend` and `.user`

Answer (score 4):

Is this? I removed `::after`

```css
.user {
  float: right;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.friend {
  float: left;
  background-color: orchid;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
 <div contenteditable="true" class="user clearfix">
    Have you completed the css chat tutorial
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="friend clearfix">
    No I did not.
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="user clearfix">
    Is it working?
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="friend clearfix">
    NO :(
  </div>
```